# How to calculate how many watts a resistor need?

Tags: hardware, power, led

I want to build the most simple circuit that connects my pi, the resistor and a LED. I looked up resistors but there are so many resistors 0.1W, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1W, 2W ,3W etc... Which one do I choose and how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watts(P) are the product of Voltage(V) and Amperage/Current(I). So if this is hooked up to the GPIO of the RPi, you know `V=3.3V` (assuming you didn't wire this up to the 5V pin). Assuming the LED has a maximum safe operating Amperage of `I=0.02A`, you can see that the Watt rating of the resistor should be at least `P=V*I=3.3*0.02 = 0.066W`. It's better to take at least double the value (so 0.125W or more) just for the sake of safety.

For completeness, the Resistance(R) of the resistor is defined by `R=V/I`, and comes out to `R=3.3/0.02=165 Ohm`. Closest typical resistor size is 220 Ohm (you want to be safe here too, but don't go too far as you will dim the LED's light).

As @goldilocks mentioned in the comments - the LED causes a voltage drop when current runs through it. Typical for LEDs this is ~2V. So the resistor calculation can be based on the residual ~1.3V, leading to a recommended `R=65 Ohm` or more (100 Ohm is a safe value).

Comment: Beat me to it.  Maybe you should include an example forward voltage drop for the LED though; e.g., `R = (3.3 - 2) / 0.02 = 65`).  IMO most LEDs 100 Ohms is safe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope I dont ask for too much but can you recommend me a book to start with electronics? I am really interested in electronics but I have no idea what I am doing. lol

Comment: Look for the book written by Forrest Mims. It's a golden oldie but gives a good intro.